# ExtEscape with CHECKPNGFORMAT failed on valid PNG data

Tags: winapi, printing

Good day everyone!

I try to implement printing function in my Win32 application. My program needs to print rather large bitmaps. But sending bitmaps directly to printer is not very effective because of the size of bitmap for one page. Fortunately, most printers now support JPEG or PNG data as input. JPEG is not very nice option for my application (because of quality loses even on 100% quality), so I try to implement printing with PNG images.

Now about implementation. MSDN says that I must check my PNG image before writing it printer DC (with SetDIBitsToDevice). For this I must call ExtEscape function with CHECKPNGFORMAT and pointer to my image data.

```
// Check that DC can answer the call to ExtEscape with CHECKPNGFORMAT
DWORD esc = CHECKPNGFORMAT;
int extEscReturn = ExtEscape(printerDC, QUERYESCSUPPORT,sizeof(esc), (char*)&esc, 0, 0);
if( extEscReturn <= 0 ) {
    return false;
}
// Check that DC can accept that particular image as PNG
DWORD checkValue = 0;
extEscReturn = ExtEscape(printerDC, CHECKPNGFORMAT, pngBufferSize, (char*)pngBuffer,
    sizeof(checkValue), (char*)&checkValue);
```

According to MSDN printing will be OK based on two conditions:
 1. ExtEscape return value (extEscReturn) must be less or equal than 0
 2. checkValue must be equal to 1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183424(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145131(v=vs.85).aspx

The problem is that for some perfectly normal PNG images function return value is fine but checkValue is 0. As far as can tell this happens a lot for images that more than 1Mb size in PNG format.
Moreover in such cases GetLastError return 0 and if I try to print the image anyway it works just fine (on my printer).

So the question is may I ignore that errors (ExtEscape return value is OK, GetLastError is zero but function checkValue is not OK) and proceed with printing in such cases? Or does this mean that for some printers or printer drivers printing will actually fail and I need to fall back to printing initial bitmap?